# Plural of "Timebox"

Tags: grammatical-number

I wonder how to refer to multiple [timeboxes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeboxing) in a German text:

> Ein Zeitplan inkl. […] sowie entsprechender Timeboxen/Timeboxes/… findet sich in Tabelle 1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Im Prinzip funktioniert beides, aber: kann man das *sowie entsprechender...* nicht ganz weglassen? *Zeitplan* impliziert schon die Bestandteile und im Zweifelsfall hilft Tabelle 1 weiter.

Comment: @guidot ich möchte eigentlich deutlich machen, dass es sich bei den Start-/Endterminen im Zeitplan lediglich um Timeboxen handelt und nicht um eine tatsächliche Aufwandsschätzung. Daher würde ich es bevorzugen, es explizit zu erwähnen. Prinzipiell könnte ich den Satz auch umformulieren, sodass ich z. B. "Timeboxing" verwenden. "Timeboxen" fühlt sich einfach nicht richtig an …

Comment: Was ist eine Timebox?

Comment: Sind die Wörter _Zeitfenster_ oder _Zeitrahmen_ nicht mehr gut genug? Oder hat _Timebox_ eine zusätzliche, von _Zeitfenster_ oder _Zeitrahmen_ nicht abgedeckte Bedeutung, sodass es eines neuen Worts bedarf?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Timebox bezieht sich auf [Timeboxing](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeboxing), eine Technik aus dem Projektmanagement. Daher halte ich ein deutsches Wort für keine gute Option. Wie bereits erwähnt, sollte ich den Satz vielleicht einfach umformulieren, damit keine Verwirrung entsteht.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In German a [***Box***](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Box) is a widely accepted loanword from English where we have no doubt about the plural form ***Boxen***.

Therefore a composite word follows the same rules. In the given example this would be:

> Die Timeboxen

This would even work with brand-new made-up words (*Rekiboxen*).

However apparently, and this is why we [see another answer that comes to a different conclusion](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38814/plural-of-timebox/38818#38818) we have two concurrent variants, a Germanised loanword *[Box/Boxen](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/box:N:F:D)*, and an adopted English term *[Box/Boxes](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/box:N:F:E)*. Both can appear simultaneously leading to somewhat inconsistent Duden entries such as [*Musicboxen*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Musicbox) in addition to Musikboxen or Musicboxes.

Im summary I believe it will not be wrong to say *Timeboxes* but in an otherwise German text I would definitely prefer to use *Timeboxen*. To keep the English term ([time box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeboxing)) we may alternatively consider *Time-Box/Time-Boxes*.

---

Die [**Box**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Box) ist ein mittlerweile gut eingedeutschtes Lehnwort aus dem Englischen, bei der über den Plural **Boxen** kein Zweifel besteht.

Analog muss man auch Komposita behandeln, somit wäre der Plural im konkreten Fall:

> Die Timeboxen

Das würde auch mit neuen Phantasiewörtern funktionieren (*Rekiboxen*).

Offenbar gibt es aber mittlerweile - und deshalb gibt es hier auch eine [Antwort mit einem anderen Ergebnis](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38814/plural-of-timebox/38818#38818) - zwei Varianten, nämlich eine eingedeutschte [*Box/Boxen*](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/box:N:F:D) und ein englisches Fremdwort [*Box/Boxes*](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/box:N:F:E). Beide können gleichzeitig vorkommen und führen dann zu solch eigentümlichen Duden-Einträgen wie [Musicboxen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Musicbox) neben Musicboxes und Musikboxen.

Zusammengefasst denke ich, es wäre nicht falsch, *Timeboxes* zu sagen, aber in einem ansonsten deutschsprachigen Text würde ich eindeutig *Timeboxen* bevorzugen. Um den englischsprachigen Ausdruck ([*time box*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeboxing)) beizubehalten kommt allenfalls noch *Time-Box/Time-Boxes* in Frage.

Comment: [Pollitzers Einwand](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/38818/26612) ist interessant. Daher würde ich das Akzeptieren der Antwort nochmal zurückziehen und warten, welchen Tenor die Community findet.

Comment: @beatngu13 Siehe Edit, weshalb das wohl so ist. Hinter den blauen Box/Boxen verbergen sich Links zu canoo.net.

Comment: Sehr gute Antwort. Wenn die deutsche Box das Grundwort ist, gilt der deutsche Plural, Boxen. Wenn das englische Wort box das Grundwort ist, kann der englische Plural verwendet werden, aber als nicht eingedeutschtes Fremdwort würde ich es dann markieren (kursivieren).

Answer (score 1):

Der Blick in den Duden zeigt:

> - eine [Box](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Box), zwei Boxen
> - eine [Blackbox](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Blackbox), zwei Blackboxes
> - eine [Bluebox](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bluebox), zwei Blueboxes

Die Pluralbildung ist also nicht einheitlich. Da es für *»Timebox«* noch keinen Eintrag gibt, liegt die Entscheidung bei dir; bei einem im Deutschen so seltenen Wort wie *»Timebox«* würde ich den Plural auf *»es«* allerdings bevorzugen.

Comment: Spannend! Ich habe das mal in meiner Antwort aufgegriffen. Wenn man bei Google sucht, findet man erstaunlich wenig *Blackboxes* oder *Blueboxes* in deutschen Texten.

Comment: Ich glaube mittlerweile, dass man, wenn man denn unbedingt das englische Fremdwort *Box* nehmen möchte, besser auf die Bildung eines Kompositums verzichtet und dafür einen Bindestrich setzt, denn das englische Wort ist schließlich auch kein Kompositum.